# Array initialization using reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

Someone please help to understand how can we initialize array in java using reflection.

for a simple object we can do like this :

```
Class l_dto_class = Class.forName(p_fld.getType().getName());
Object l_dto_obj= l_dto_class.newInstance();
```

but for the case of array it is giving me exception.

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that cause the exception?

Comment: In order to call `newInstance()` you must have a zero args constructor and I don't think `Array` meets that requirement...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can instantiate array like this:

```
if (l_dto_class.isArray()) {
        Object aObject = Array.newInstance(l_dto_class, 5); //5 is length
        int length = Array.getLength(aObject); // will be 5
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
            Array.set(aObject, i, "someVal"); // set your val here
    }
}
```

Comment: To create array of l_dto_class items you need to get component class and pass it to newInstance method:
`Array.newInstance(l_dto_class.getComponentClass(), 5)`

Answer (score 11):

There is a class for Array in reflection [java.lang.reflect.Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)

```
int[] test = (int[])Array.newInstance(int.class, 3);
```

Comment: Note that you need to change `test[3]` to `test[]`.